# OrderForm' object has no attribute 'get' via request.post

Tags: python, django

I've created an orderform and was trying to extract information from the form. However, each time when i called for forms.get("firstname") or anything, i will face the error that the object has no attribute 'get" even though it is a form. more specifically, the error is "AttributeError: 'OrderForm' object has no attribute 'get'"

Here is the relevant code:

in models.py:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    eid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    class Meta: abstract = True
 
    @classmethod
    def get_or_none(cls, **kwargs):
        try:
            return cls.objects.get(**kwargs)
        except cls.DoesNotExist:
            return None

class Order(BaseModel):
    
    itemname = models.CharField(max_length =100, default="")
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    email = models.EmailField()
    phone = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False)
    comments = models.TextField()
    delivery = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.eid)
```

in forms.py:

```
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    itemname = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Post.objects.filter(title__contains="Bae"), required=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ('itemname', 'firstname', 'lastname', 'email', 'phone','delivery', 'comments')
        labels = {'itemname': 'Order Item', 'firstname': 'First Name', 'lastname':"Last Name", 'email':"Email", 'phone':"Phone Number", 'delivery':'Deliver?', 'comments':'Comments'}
```

in views.py. This is where the error occurs:

```
def order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save(commit=False)

            item_selected = form.get('itemname')

            order.itemname = item_selected
            order.save()
            return render(request, 'Reddit_app/order_thankyou.html')
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
    return render(request, 'Reddit_app/order_from_post.html', {"form": form})
```

finally, the order html code is :

```
        <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
item_selected = form.cleaned_data.get('itemname')
```

if you want to access data from form you need to access `cleaned_data` after the is_valid function is invoked